# atomic reference to Set - adding values

Tags: scala

I defined an atomic reference as a Set:

`var RT = new AtomicReference[Set[String]](null)`

but I'm not able to add anything there :

```
 scala> RT  = RT + ("Z")
 <console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference[Set[String]]
       RT  = RT + ("Z")
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after?

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic._
val RT = new AtomicReference[Set[String]](Set.empty[String])

RT.accumulateAndGet(Set("Z"), _ ++ _) //res0: Set[String] = Set(Z)
RT.accumulateAndGet(Set("w"), _ ++ _) //res1: Set[String] = Set(Z, w)
RT.updateAndGet(_ + "cc")             //res2: Set[String] = Set(Z, w, cc)
```

Comment: yes ! and how to convert it to seq ?

Comment: @LwicaGorska; `RT.get.toSeq`